# Quantifier elimination for Boolean algebras

Tags: logic, model-theory, boolean-algebra, quantifier-elimination

Is there a reference in English for the proof that Boolean algebras admit quantifier elimination? I'm interested in how quantifier elimination can be performed. However, the result of Tarski is not complete and the paper of Ershov is in Russian. Moreover, the book of Chang and Keisler uses Ehrenfeucht Fraissé games instead of doing the quantifier elimination procedure. It seems an important enough result to be written somewhere? Otherwise, did Ershov show how to do quantifier elimination?

Comment: I guess you mean the atomless Boolean algebras. (Infinite) atomic Boolean algebras don't admit q.e., since there is no quantifier-free formula defining the set of atoms.

Comment: If you know Fraisse theory, then I think the easiest argument is that a countable atomless Boolean algebra is uniformly locally finite and ultrahomogeneous. Then any atomless Boolean algebra has a countable elementary submodel.

Comment: @tomasz i guess there is quantifier elimination in a suitable extended signature. see for example Chang and Keisler theorem 5.5.10 where it says "The sufficiency can be proved in any one of several ways. For example, it could be done by the method of elimination of quantifiers". I am explicitly interested in the elimination of quantifiers.

Comment: Well, you can always extend the signature to force q.e. I guess for Boolean algebras, it might be enough to add for each $n$ a unary predicate $P_n$ which says that there are precisely $n$ atoms below, and a predicate $Q$ saying "I'm the sup of a finite set of atoms", or something of the sort.

Comment: Okay, looking at Keisler&Chang, it seems like the language ought to be a bit more complicated than that for an arbitrary Boolean algebra. Anyway, my original point stands: Boolean algebras don't really admit quantifier elimination in any of the standard languages for Boolean algebras.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4274676/quantifier-elimination-for-the-theory-of-infinite-atomic-boolean-algebra looks relevant.

Comment: Do the reviews of Ershov's paper (in Math. Reviews or Zentralblatt or The Journal of Symbolic Logic) provide any details?

Comment: https://zbmath.org/scans/199/031.gif
https://www.jstor.org/stable/2271013?sid=primo&origin=crossref